# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 'nom_complet' inconnu dans field list

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table "candidat". When I want to display selected items I got this message

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054   Champ 'nom_complet' inconnu dans field list' in C:\wamp\www\CVtheque\Model\Connexion.php on line 78

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 'nom_complet' inconnu dans field list in C:\wamp\www\CVtheque\Model\Connexion.php on line 78
```

Table candidat:

```
CREATE TABLE candidat (
  id_candidat  int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  civ  varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  nom_complet  varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  email  varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  pass  varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  tel varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  adresse varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  pays varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  ville varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  cv varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  niv varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  fonction varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  profil varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  nbre_exp varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  dispo varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  tech varchar(300) NOT NULL )
```

Connexion.php:

```
 Class Connexion {
  private $host = "localhost";
  private $user = "root";
  private $pass = "";
  private $dbname = "cvtheque";
  private $dbh;
  private $stmt;

    public function __construct() {
      $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
      $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
        );
        try {
          $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
          echo "Erreur de la connexion: " . $e->getMessage();
     }
   }
    public function get_connexion() {
      $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
      $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );

        try {
          $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
     }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
          echo "Connexion Error: " . $e->getMessage();
     }
     return $this->dbh;
 }

    public function query($query) {
      $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
}

    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null) {
      if (is_null($type)) {
        switch (true) {
            case is_int($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                break;
            case is_bool($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                break;
            case is_null($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                break;
            default:
                $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
        }
      }
    $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }

    public function execute() {
      return $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    // returns an array of the result set rows
    public function resultset() {
      $this->execute();
      return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    //returns a single record from the database
    public function single() {
      $this->execute();
      return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     }

    //returns the nb of effected rows from the previous delete, update or insert statement
    public function rowCount() {
      return $this->stmt->rowCount();
     }

    public function lastInsertId() {
      return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
     }

    public function beginTransaction() {
      return $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
     }

    //end a transaction and commit your changes:
    public function endTransaction() {
      return $this->dbh->commit();
     }
    //cancel a transaction and roll back your changes:
    public function cancelTransaction() {
      return $this->dbh->rollBack();
     }

    public function debugDumpParams() {
      return $this->stmt->debugDumpParams();
     }
}
```

search.php:

```
<html>
  <head>
        <title>Test de la recherche</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
        <form method="POST" action="Datatable.php">
            Fonction: <select name="fonc">
                        <option value="0">Tous</option>
                        <option value="1"> Agriculture / Pêche / Navigation  </option>
                        <option value="2"> Architecture / Urbanisme / Environnement  </option>
                        <option value="3"> Artisanat  </option>
                        <option value="4"> Banque / Assurance  </option>
                        <option value="5"> BTP / Extraction  </option>
                        <option value="6"> Commerce / Distribution / Vente / Import-export  </option>
                        <option value="7"> Communication / Publicité  </option>
                        <option value="8"> Comptabilité / Gestion / Audit  </option>
                        <option value="9"> Conseil / Consulting  </option>
                        <option value="10"> Direction / Gérance  </option>
                        <option value="11"> Electricité / Electronique / Electrotechnique  </option>
                        <option value="12"> Achats  </option>
                        <option value="13"> Enseignement / Formation / Traduction  </option>
                        <option value="14"> Immobilier  </option>
                        <option value="15"> Informatique / Internet / Multimedia  </option>
                        <option value="16"> Journalisme / Audiovisuel / Médias  </option>
                        <option value="17"> Juridique / Droit  </option>
                        <option value="18"> Logistique / Transport  </option>
                        <option value="19"> Marketing  </option>
                        <option value="20"> Métiers des centres d'appels  </option>
                        <option value="21"> Production / Maintenance  </option>
                        <option value="22"> Qualité / Sécurité / Hygiène / Environnement  </option>
                        <option value="23"> R &amp; D  </option>
                        <option value="24"> RH / Recrutement / Formation  </option>
                        <option value="25"> Santé / Professions médicales  </option>
                        <option value="26"> Secrétariat / Services Généraux  </option>
                        <option value="27"> Télécoms / Réseaux  </option>
            </select><br/>
            Nombre d'experience: <input type="text" name="nex" ><br/>
            Disponibilité: <input type="text"name="dispo"><br/>
            Téchnologies: <textarea name="tech" rows="4" cols="50" class="textfield"></textarea><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="valider" />
        </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

here is the page that should display results in datatble

```
<?php
require_once '../Model/Connexion.php';
$fonc = $_POST['fonc'];
$nex = $_POST['nex'];
$dispo = $_POST['dispo'];
$tech = $_POST['tech'];
$c = new Connexion();
$c->query("select nom_complet,fonction,email,nbre_exp,dispo,tech from candidat "
        . "where fonction = :fonc and nbre_exp = :nexp and dispo = :dispo and tech = :tech");
$c->bind(':fonc', '$fonc');//pour éviter l'injection SQL
$c->bind(':nexp', '$nex');//pour éviter l'injection SQL
$c->bind(':dispo', '$dispo');//pour éviter l'injection SQL
$c->bind(':tech', '$tech');//pour éviter l'injection SQL
$rows = $c->resultset();
?>
<html>
    <head>
                <title>Search results</title>
<   /head>
<?php
        $c->query("SELECT nom_complet, fonction, email, nbre_exp,dispo,tech "
                . "FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME="."'candidat'");
        $cl = $c->single();
    ?>
    <body>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><?php echo($cl['nom_complet']); ?></th>
                            <th><?php echo($cl['fonction']); ?></th>
                            <th><?php echo($cl['email']); ?></th>
                            <th><?php echo($cl['nbre_exp']); ?></th>
                            <th><?php echo($cl['dispo']); ?></th>
                            <th><?php echo($cl['tech']); ?></th>
                        </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th><?php echo($cl['nom_complet']); ?></th>
                            <th><?php echo($cl['fonction']); ?></th>
                            <th><?php echo ($cl['email']); ?></th>
                            <th><?php echo($cl['nbre_exp']); ?></th>
                            <th><?php echo($cl['dispo']); ?></th>
                            <th><?php echo($cl['tech']); ?></th>
                        </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                    <?php foreach($rows as $r) {  ?>
                        <tr class="odd_gradeX">
                                <td class="read_only"><?php echo($r['nom_complet']) ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo($r['fonction']) ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo($r['email']) ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo($r['nbre_exp']) ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo($r['dispo']) ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo($r['tech']) ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>            
                </tbody>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

I want to make a search in a form and display the results into another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, refer to MySQL documentation about [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS Table`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html).

Try to use SQL like this: **`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='candidat' AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('nom_complet', 'fonction', 'email', 'nbre_exp', 'dispo', 'tech');`**

Then use `$cl = $c->resultset();`

Then use `foreach` to get all data from `$cl` that you need and show it on your page.

Comment: how i use foreach for <th> ?

Comment: What data you'd like to see in your's TH's tags? See `http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html` and let me know what column value you'd like to see at your <th>.

Comment: i would displays columns name in table head

Comment: In this case use something like

`<th>nom_complet</th><th>fonction</th><th>email</th><th>nbre_exp</th><th>dispo</th><th>tech</th>`

Or say where you store names for each column.

Answer (score 1):

You do this:

```
$c->query("SELECT nom_complet, fonction, email, nbre_exp,dispo,tech "
        . "FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME="."'candidat'");
```

My guess is that table `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` does not contain a column called `nom_complet`.